# List sub levels in Unreal Blueprint

Tags: c++, unreal-blueprint, blueprint

In Unreal one has the main level and then sub levels that can be streamed in or removed during game play.
I ran into a problem of listing all the sublevels whether they are currently loaded or not, so I can make sure all are unloaded before loading the desired levels.

So I need to list all the sub levels.

Comment: There's an option in the editor view-port: `Show Stats` and `Stats > Engine > Levels` to see what levels are loaded/unloaded while play-testing. You can also just use the Level's name to stream it in without having a reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    /** Get a list of level names that are streaming (sub-levels) */
UFUNCTION(BlueprintPure, Category = "My BP Library|Levels")
    static TArray<FString> MyGetStreamingLevels(UObject* WorldContextObject, bool& Success);
```

And the implementation is...

```
#include "Engine/LevelStreaming.h"
```

...

```
TArray<FString> UMyBPUtilsLibrary::MyGetStreamingLevels(UObject* WorldContextObject, bool& Success) {
TArray<FString> ret;
if (!WorldContextObject) {
    ret.Add(FString(TEXT("Error: No WorldContextObject?")));
    Success = false;
    return ret;
}
if (!WorldContextObject->GetWorld()) {
    ret.Add(FString(TEXT("Error: No world object?")));
    Success = false;
    return ret;
}
auto streamedLevels = WorldContextObject->GetWorld()->GetStreamingLevels();

for (ULevelStreaming* lvl : streamedLevels) {
    FString f = lvl->GetWorldAssetPackageName();
    // f is like "/Game/Maps/Notch_Peak_Master", or in the editor "/Game/Maps/UEDPIE_0_Notch_Peak_Master"
    // Chop at last slash in path if any.
    int i;
    if (f.FindLastChar('/', i)) {
        f = f.RightChop(i + 1);
    }
    // Now f is like "UEDPIE_0_Notch_Peak_Master" or "Notch_Peak_Master"
    // In the editor?
    if (f.StartsWith(TEXT("UEDPIE"))) {
        f.RemoveFromStart(TEXT("UEDPIE"));
        // Like "_2_" being the local simulated player number.
        if (f.RemoveFromStart(TEXT("_")) && f.Len() > 2 && f[1] == '_') {
            f.RemoveFromStart(TEXT("0"));
            f.RemoveFromStart(TEXT("1"));
            f.RemoveFromStart(TEXT("2"));
            f.RemoveFromStart(TEXT("3"));
            f.RemoveFromStart(TEXT("4"));
            f.RemoveFromStart(TEXT("5"));
            f.RemoveFromStart(TEXT("6"));
            f.RemoveFromStart(TEXT("7"));
            f.RemoveFromStart(TEXT("8"));
            f.RemoveFromStart(TEXT("_"));
        }
    }

    ret.Add(f);

}
Success = true;
return ret;
```

}